# Request for Multi-dimensional simulation reference book

Tags: references, simulation, finance, stochastic-calculus

Do you have any reference book about multi-dimensional simulation? The random variables are not identically distributed and are correlated.

I understand the procedure to generate correlated normal distributions but have no idea for this general cases.

Background: got a bachelor degree in mathematics.

Comment: The question is unclear: do you want to simulate a specific multivariate distribution, in which case how is it defined? Or do you ask for existing methods for standard distributions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All books on simulation, like

- [Devroye's Random Variate Generation](http://amzn.to/2pItGTg)
- [Fishman's Monte Carlo](http://amzn.to/2pIvzAa)
- [Rubinstein's and Kroese's Simulation and the Monte Carlo Method](http://amzn.to/2qCX9Ti)
- and our own book [Monte Carlo Statistical Methods](http://amzn.to/2pIX8cw)

contain entries on how to simulate joint distributions. Depending on how the joint distribution is defined, there are several general principles to produce such simulations:

1. if the successive conditionals, $f_1(x_1)$, $f_2(x_2|x_1)$, $f_3(x_3|x_1,x_2)$, &tc., can be simulated, producing a joint simulation means simulating the first, then the second, &tc. univariate distributions;
2. if the joint density $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is available in closed form, then different MCMC methods can be applied to this target as, e.g., the Gibbs sampler;

   3. if the joint distribution can be expressed as a copula, then simulation of a joint uniform over $[0,1]^n$ is sufficient, followed by a deterministic transform by the inverse cdf's for each component.